# Comparing two bash variables

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a simple Bash script that shows the difference between two variables, with the assumption that both variables contain identical parameters with different values. Look at `$sam` and `$pish` variables. They are identical, except parameter `driver_mode` is `1` in `$sam`, and `2` in `$pish`. To do this comparison, I store each variable into a separate array, and then compare each element one by one.

```
#!/bin/bash

sam="driver_mode=2 firmware_path=/home/release/firmware/ onebox_zone_enabled=0x10001 ta_aggr=4 skip_fw_load=0 fw_load_mode=1 sdio_clock=40000 enable_antenna_diversity=0 coex_mode=1 obm_ant_sel_val=2 wlan_rf_power_mode=0 bt_rf_power_mode=0 zigb_rf_power_mode=0 country_code=840  bt_rf_tx_power_mode=1 bt_rf_rx_power_mode=0"

pish="driver_mode=1 firmware_path=/home/release/firmware/ onebox_zone_enabled=0x10001 ta_aggr=4 skip_fw_load=0 fw_load_mode=1 sdio_clock=40000 enable_antenna_diversity=0 coex_mode=1 obm_ant_sel_val=2 wlan_rf_power_mode=0 bt_rf_power_mode=0 zigb_rf_power_mode=0 country_code=840  bt_rf_tx_power_mode=1 bt_rf_rx_power_mode=0"

read -r -a array_old <<< "$sam"

read -r -a array_new <<< "$pish"

for index in "${!array_old[@]}"; do
    if [[ ${array_old[index]} -ne ${array_new[index]} ]]; then
        echo ${array_old[index]} 'to' ${array_new[index]}     
    fi
done
```

Running the above bash script gives me error:

> ./test: line 12: firmware_path=/home/release/firmware/: syntax error:
>   operand expected (error token is "/home/release/firmware/")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-ne` operator is an integer [comparison operator](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html). To compare strings use `!=`:

```
for index in "${!array_old[@]}"; do
  if [[ ${array_old[index]} != "${array_new[index]}" ]]; then
    echo ${array_old[index]} 'to' ${array_new[index]}     
  fi
done
```

Comment: I'd like to +1 because of your first paragraph, but then your last one cancels it out by being wrong in the exact way that the first paragraph was right. (Namely: the reason you can write `index` rather than `$index` is that array indices are an arithmetic context, exactly like the arguments of `-ne`.)

Comment: @ruakh it's fixed now ;-)

Comment: @ruakh, indeed, as `${!array_old[@]}` expands to numeric indices. I'm used to use indices in string context, and completely forgot about this feature. Thanks.